Transaction is unconfirmed
This transaction is unconfirmed, is there any thing I can do to make it faster? Is the BTC recoverable if it never gets confirmed?
f7d89f931080642a718575e0d103e8bc755dde6bae362c3d6e1c674b0d396284
